# Filtering datatable number column

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, datatable

i would like to filter a datatable by a column which contains number data, i'm trying the following:

```
string selected = colSelect.GetItemText(colSelect.SelectedItem);
if (filterText.Text.Length == 0) 
{
     data_table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
}
else
{
     data_table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Price Like '%{0}%'", filterText.Text);
```

I've tried casting the second value to a string but no luck, i get the error:

> Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Decimal and System.String

The data entered would be any number or text, but based on the data only relevant number values would show with the filter.

Comment: Is column 'Price' a string column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Price` column is `decimal` typed but you supplied a `string` which is `filterText.Text` to filter it.

One solution might be using `CONVERT` which is explained in [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) documentation like;

```
data_table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CONVERT(Price, 'System.String') like '%" + filterText.Text + "%'";
```

I didn't tried this one but you can parse your `filterText.Text` to `decimal` (if it is valid one) and use it like;

```
data_table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Price Like '%" + decimal.Parse(filterText.Text) + "%'";
```

But as I said, I an not %100 sure for the second one.

Comment: That's did the trick, i was simply passing the data into the datatable without any datatype modification and just expected it to be a string based on an incorrect spec *sigh*, cheers :)